# Insert array into PDO (PHP): "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Inserting an array via PDO into a MySQL-Database with PHP doesn't work for me. It says "invalid parameter number", even though the array has 41 values; the PDO names 41 columns; and the prepared query has 41 question marks.

The array has 41 values (I checked with var_dump), like this:

```
$data = [
    'countrycode' => $_GET["id"],
    'country' => $_GET["country"],
    'region' => $_GET["region"],
    'law_db_region' => $_GET["law_db_region"],
    [... etc ...]
 ]
```

My PDO code is the following (yep, these are 41 columns & 41 question marks):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO awards_country
    (countrycode, country, region, law_db_region, law_db_national,
    law_db_national2, const_url, const_version, const_date, const_dummy,
    const_article, const_wording, const_article2, const_wording2, const_article3,
    const_wording3, law_dummy, law_act, law_article, law_source,
    law_date, law_act2, law_article2, law_source2, law_date2,
    law_act3, law_article3, law_source3, law_date3, web_dummy,
    web_url, web_organ, web_language, web_date, web_url2,
    web_organ2, web_language2, web_date2, wikipedia_url, wikipedia_date,
    comment)

    VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )";
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

The error I get is nevertheless:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in [...]country-insert.php:99
>
> Stack trace: #0 [...]country-insert.php(99):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /data/web/e96483/html/awards/country-insert.php on line 99

Comment: It's been a long time since I tested, but this might be due to your `$data` array having associative keys, while you are using positional `?` in the statement. This might be easily solvable with `$stmt->execute(array_values($data))` to replace the associative array keys with numeric keys. Or solvable by just creating a plain array in the first place `$data = [$_GET['id'], $_GET['country'],....]`

Comment: `print_r( $data );` before PDO execute to make sure it contains all fields you need.

Comment: I know this is after you've fixed it, but could I recommend that if your using PDO to stick with an associative array and change the `?` in the query to named parameters - `:countrycode` etc.  This means it is easier to ensure that the right value is put into the right field, just an array of 41 fields can be easy to misalign if you add 1 field in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer, but a recommendation (and to large for a comment).

Extracted from your code and reformatted for clearness:

```
const_article,  const_wording,
const_article2, const_wording2,
const_article3, const_wording3,
...
law_act,  law_article,  law_source,  law_date,
law_act2, law_article2, law_source2, law_date2,
law_act3, law_article3, law_source3, law_date3,
```

It seems, that this is a 1:N relation. And you are working with relational database system (mysql). So why not use relations and one or more additional tables?

In fact, not using relations here will make other (future) request much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, Wiimm, I did not think about that. Your recommendation seems indeed very useful!

Answer (score 1):

for ? param  you should not  use  an associative array  but pass  values  as a positional

```
$data = [
    $_GET["id"],
    $_GET["country"],
    $_GET["region"],
     $_GET["law_db_region"],
    [... etc ...]
 ]
```